# Why Findbugs cannot detect my code error?

Tags: java, exception, findbugs, runtimeexception

I have read the bug detectors in findbugs website, http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html

I want to write a test code and use Findbugs to detect the REC error.
But the findbugs cannot. Why? Could you help me to solve this?

Thanks,

Below is the description in Findbugs.

REC: Exception is caught when Exception is not thrown (REC_CATCH_EXCEPTION)

This method uses a try-catch block that catches Exception objects, but Exception is not thrown within the try block, and RuntimeException is not explicitly caught. It is a common bug pattern to say try { ... } catch (Exception e) { something } as a shorthand for catching a number of types of exception each of whose catch blocks is identical, but this construct also accidentally catches RuntimeException as well, masking potential bugs.

A better approach is to either explicitly catch the specific exceptions that are thrown, or to explicitly catch RuntimeException exception, rethrow it, and then catch all non-Runtime Exceptions, as shown below:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    throw e;
} catch (Exception e) {
    ... deal with all non-runtime exceptions ...
}
```

My code is:

public static void test1(){

```
    int A[] = {1,2,3};

    int result = 5/0;//divided by 0
    int arrOut = A[0]+A[4];//index out of bound
    System.out.println(arrOut);
    System.out.println(result);
    try {

    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("Runtimeex throw");
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("An try error occurred: 0 cannot be divided");
    } 

}
```

Comment: Note that FindBugs works on the .class files, so stuff that the compiler removes, such as unused or unreachable code, will not be visible to FindBugs. Your try-block will be removed  because it does nothing. So for testing, always construct cases that actually execute.

Comment: Thanks, How can I write a sample code that Findbugs can detect the REC error?

Answer (score 3):

The `try` is where the exception occur that you want to catch. However, since it is occurring out of the `try` block, the exception is not caught by the catch part, which is why FindBugs reporting it as a useless `try {...} catch {...}` code. The proper code should be as follows.

```
int A[] = {1,2,3};

try {
    int result = 5/0;//divided by 0
    int arrOut = A[0]+A[4];//index out of bound
    System.out.println(arrOut);
    System.out.println(result);
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    System.out.println("Runtimeex throw");
    throw e;
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
    System.out.println("An try error occurred: 0 cannot be divided");
}
```

}

Comment: I use findbugs on this code, but it still cannot detect the REC error, How can I do that?...

Comment: Because you have the catch `Exception`

Comment: You must only have catches that are for non-runtime exceptions.